# Set two y-axis color in a subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis, subplot

In the matlab documentation it says that it is possible to change the Matlab axis colors in a two y-axis figure by doing the following:

```
fig = figure;
left_color = [.5 .5 0];
right_color = [0 .5 .5];
set(fig,'defaultAxesColorOrder',[left_color; right_color]);

y = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
yyaxis left
plot(y)

z = [6 5 4; 3 2 1];
yyaxis right
plot(z)
```

This works and produces the desired output.

[image]

Now I was trying to do the exact same figure but in a subplot. My code is the following:

```
fig = subplot(2,1,1);
left_color = [.5 .5 0];
right_color = [0 .5 .5];
set(fig,'defaultAxesColorOrder',[left_color; right_color]);

y = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
yyaxis left
plot(y)

z = [6 5 4; 3 2 1];
yyaxis right
plot(z)
```

[image]

Here, however, it does not change the axis colors. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fig` is a handle to an axes, not the figure:

```
fig = subplot(2,1,1);
```

However, when you set the `'defaultAxesColorOrder'` property you set it at the figure level for all axes within it, as written in [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/customize-graph-with-two-y-axes.html?searchHighlight=defaultAxesColorOrder&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#bvlni8s-1):

> Set the default value at the figure level so that the new colors affect only axes that are children of the figure `fig`.

all you need to do to fix that is define `fig` as a figure, and move the subplot command after you set the `'defaultAxesColorOrder'` property:

```
fig = figure;  %<-- you change here
left_color = [.5 .5 0];
right_color = [0 .5 .5];
set(fig,'defaultAxesColorOrder',[left_color; right_color]);

subplot(2,1,1) %<-- and add that
y = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
yyaxis left
plot(y)

z = [6 5 4; 3 2 1];
yyaxis right
plot(z)
```

[image]